# Which features of a website should we test with Protractor in E2E testing?

Tags: protractor, e-commerce, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

Which features of an angular or a non-angular website should we exactly write tests for with Protractor in E2E testing ? Specially for an e_commerce website.

Comment: There is no universal answer to this question unfortunately, the answer depends on a lot of different things. If you have zero end-to-end tests and a working application, focus on the critical parts first - the parts that are involved in generating revenue, mission-critical. And/or focus on the parts that are the most complicated in terms of implementation. Start with covering as much functionality as possible and only then dive into separate parts of the application - in other words, go wide first, not deep. This is, of course, just my opinion. I know nothing about your application under test

Comment: I think this is more general testing question than specific to protractor or even automation.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I asked specific to protractor because i only know only a little about e2e testing and i need to write tests using protractor.

Comment: @alecxe I got your point , now I got idea which things to keep in mind while writing tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no correct or not correct answers. But first You should start with smoke test or modules that are often changed (current regression pack), because here is where the most bugs are found.